# How to create excel file with SharedStringTablePart using DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

There is code which works with Excel like this:

```
using SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("filePath", true);
    
WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart!;

SheetData sheetData = GetSheetData(workbookPart, outFile);
    
Worksheet worksheet = sheetData.Parent as Worksheet;

List<SharedStringItem> sharedStringTableElements = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart!.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ToList();

List<Row> sheetRows = sheetData.Elements<Row>().ToList();

...
```

But it breaks when I try to open my generated file. SharedStringTablePart is null.
This is how I create Excel files:

```
using SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = CreateSpreadsheet(filePath);
WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheet.AddWorkbookPart();
workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();

SheetData sheetData = new();
worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
string relationshipId = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart);

Sheet sheet = new() {
    Id = relationshipId,
    SheetId = FirstSheetId,
    Name = "SheetName",
};

sheets.Append(sheet);

//fill sheetData here

workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
spreadSheet.Close();
```

How do I change this code so it doesn't break when accessing a SharedStringTablePart? How can I fill it in correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You create a new `SpreadsheetDocument` and add the `WorkbookPart`. Right after being created, that new `WorkbookPart` does not have any associated parts. Thus, you'll have to create all required parts, including the `SharedStringTablePart`, like so:

```cs
// Let's assume you created the WorkbookPart as follows.
WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheet.AddWorkbookPart();

// Create and initialize the associated SharedStringTablePart as well.
var sharedStringTablePart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<SharedStringTablePart>();
sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable = new SharedStringTable();
```

Once added as shown above, `workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart` will no longer be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I came back to write how I did it.
First of all, we need to create `SharedStringTablePart` as Thomas said:

```
    private static SharedStringTablePart GetSharedStringTablePart(SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet)
    {
        if (spreadSheet.WorkbookPart!.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().Any())
        {
            return spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
        }
        else
        {
            return spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<SharedStringTablePart>();
        }
    }
```

Then I created a helper method to insert the data into this table:

```
    private static string InsertSharedStringItem(string text, SharedStringTablePart shareStringPart)
    {
        shareStringPart.SharedStringTable ??= new SharedStringTable();

        int i = 0;

        foreach (SharedStringItem item in shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>())
        {
            if (item.InnerText == text)
            {
                return i.ToString();
            }

            i++;
        }

        shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.AppendChild(new SharedStringItem(new Text(text)));
        shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.Save();

        return i.ToString();
    }
```

So next time when I inserting cell value I do it like this:

```
                string index = InsertSharedStringItem("some text", sharedTablePart);

                Cell cell = new() {
                    DataType = CellValues.SharedString,
                    CellValue = new CellValue(index),
                    ...
                };
                row.AppendChild(cell);
```